# Complexity of an specific algorithm with 3 for?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a question if you can tell me if i do it right!
We have this algorithm

```
for(i=0;i<n*n;i++){
  for(j=i;j<n;j++)
     for(k=0;j<=9;k++)
              c+=2;
```

I want to find complexity of this if you can tell me if i doing right

```
sum 0,n*n (sum i,n(20))= sum 0,n*n ((n-i+1)*20) = sum 0,n*n (n) - sum 0,n*n (i) + n*n*20
=nn20 + (nn-0+1)(n) -sum 0,n*n (i)
=n*n*n+nn20 -sum 0,n*n (i)
```

so `O(n*n*n)`

Is this right ?

Comment: `for(k=0;j<=9;k++)` -> `for(k=0;k<=9;k++)` (else infinite loop and currently UB)

Comment: even if you fix as Jarod42 mentioned, its O(n*n), `(j=i;j<n;j++)` will only run when `i < n`.

Comment: that's right, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Complexity of:

```
for(i=0;i<n*n;i++)
  for(j=i;j<n;j++)
     for(k=0;k<=9;k++)
              c+=2;
```

Start with inner loop:

`for(k=0;k<=9;k++)` -> 10, so constant: `O(1)`.

`for(i=0;i<n*n;i++)` would be `O(n²)`, but the tricky

`for(j=i;j<n;j++)` discards any value `i >= n`.

so it becomes

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  for(j=i;j<n;j++)
     for(k=0;k<=9;k++)
              c+=2;
for(i=n;i<n*n;i++) {}
```

Last loop `for(i=n;i<n*n;i++)` is `O(n²)` (but as no-op could be discarded by compiler)

- `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` is `O(n)`
- `for(j=i;j<n;j++)` is `O(n)` (as `O(n/2)` is `O(n)`)

So final result is `O(n²) + O(n²)` so `O(n²)`.

Comment: @walnut: wording improved

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
c+=2;
```

is called exactly

```
10 (n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1) = 5n² + 5n = 10 * sum i=1,n (i)
```

times. This is O(n²). The loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
```

iterates `n*n` times but if `i >= n` it does nothing. So effectively the outer loop iterates `n * (n-1)` times with constant complexity (O(1), it does nothing).

The loop

```
for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
```

iterates `n - i` times. And the loop

```
for(int k=0; k <= 9;k++)
```

iterates 10 times.

This is

```
10 (n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1) = 5n² + 5n = 10 * sum i=1,n (i)
```

With this code you can confirm the number of calls to `c += 2`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int n = 1; n < 10; ++n) {
        int c = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
            for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
                for(int k=0; k <= 9;k++)
                    c+=2;
        std::cout << c / 2 << " == " << "5*" << n << "*" << n << " + 5*" << n << " : " << std::boolalpha << (c / 2 == 5*n*n + 5*n) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Result:

```
10 == 5*1*1 + 5*1 : true
30 == 5*2*2 + 5*2 : true
60 == 5*3*3 + 5*3 : true
100 == 5*4*4 + 5*4 : true
150 == 5*5*5 + 5*5 : true
210 == 5*6*6 + 5*6 : true
280 == 5*7*7 + 5*7 : true
360 == 5*8*8 + 5*8 : true
450 == 5*9*9 + 5*9 : true
```

Comment: “but if `i >= n` [the outer loop] does nothing so effectively it's `n` times.” — Nooo. The outer loop is definitely executed n^2 times, Both theoretically and effectively. It’s just that, for i>n, its loop body has constant runtime.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ok, changed it.

Comment: Nice. Good answer now.